# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 broke git repository interface

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015, updates

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and I have a git repository cloned directly from the Visual Studio.

The recent update from Visual Studio from 2015 to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 led to a malfunction in the git repository tracking changes menu (under 'Team Explorer' Changes). 
Therefore, no commits are allowed through the application (due to the fact that MVS2015 does not recognize any changes).

Git commands used through command line are working (using Git for Windows), proving that this is not a repository-related problem ('git status' shows changes not staged for commit and untracked files, 'git add', 'git commit' and 'git push' allow to push new commits).

However, MVS seems to not be recognizing these changes. 
Such problem persists with and without official GitHub extension. Uninstalling GitHub extension and using MVS already included git interface results in the same error. Therefore, the problem seems to be independent of the GitHub extension and exclusively MVS related.

Comment: I have the same problem - visual studio 2015 update 1. Git source control in VS 2015 appears to be broken., It works fine for a few minutes, but then the status icons next to each file changes to the small blue padlock as though there are no changes and the changes pages of Team Explorer indicate there have been no changes. Have to close visual studio and re-open, quickly load project and attempt to check in changes before they disappear again. Hopefully someone can offer up some advice on what might be the cause.

Comment: Same problem here. We need a fix as soon as possible, Microsoft.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problems with Update 3 as well.  It is quite obnoxious to have to close and re-open studio to see changes reflected correctly.

Comment: Check my answer @WiredWiz.

Comment: Thank you @DavidNogueira, unfortunately, my installation continues to exhibit this problem even after adding the suggested files to the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding the *.VC.opendb and *.VC.db files to the .gitignore file of repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are also problems with VS 2015 in Windows 10 because of a jfm file in database projects.  See [this issue with JFM files and Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704514/visual-studio-2015-database-project-directory-contains-a-file-with-extension-jfm).  Adding *.jfm to .gitignore may fix the problem, but any .jfm files might also need to be removed from the repository.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14153876)

Comment: My symptoms were exactly the same as described in the question.  Git stopped working in VS because of Git was halting after having an error trying to access a .jfm file.  The answer was provided in the link.  Those who have a broken Git interface should also look at the JFM files as a source of problems.