# Visual Studio is locking .jfm files

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

(Using Visual Studio 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3)

My problem is much like this one -

[Visual Studio 2015 Database Project directory contains a file with extension jfm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704514/visual-studio-2015-database-project-directory-contains-a-file-with-extension-jfm)

The approved answer is to edit the gitignore file to exclude this files.

But I'm using Visual Studio Online, not GIT, and there is no GitIgnore file for this solution.

I'm stumped. Any ideas

Comment: What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a .tfignore file and not a .gitignore file. They are similar but the former is for TFVC and the latter for GIT.

See the 'Customize which files are ignored by version control' section of [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server) document

Comment: I think you're right. I tried following the steps here -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768954/visual-studio-2015-tfs-tfignore-file

But when I try adding .jfm to the ignore list I get a pop-up telling me that it can't access one of the other .jfm files because it's in use by another process.

Comment: @TRH Restart you machine and try to add .jfm to ignore list. You can create a new project and try to add ignore file.

Comment: Hi, for me this doesn't fixed the issue. *.jfm is on both my local and remote .tfignore. Still getting jfm errors, the same situation with other team members...