# Visual Studio ignores *.jfm entry in the gitIgnore file

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gitignore

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio 2013 locking a .jfm file. I am unable to save project changes to the local git repository when the project is open.

The error looks like this when clicking on the **Commit** button in the *Team Explorer -> Changes* panel:

> "An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open 'C:/Uers/Username/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/ProjectName/ProjectNameSQL/ProjectNameSQL.jfm': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

For example, when I make a change to the *default.aspx* in the project and look for changes in the Changes panel, only the *default.aspx.designer.vb* and *default.asp.vb* files show that changes have been made. only after closing the solution do I see a third file, *default.aspx*, appear in the Included Changes list of files.

I have already added *.jfm* to *.gitignore* and cleared the cache as noted in a previous solution described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704514/visual-studio-2015-database-project-directory-contains-a-file-with-extension-jfm).

I am using the visualstudio.com git repository to sync changes and have  manually edited the *.gitignore* file there as well.

How would I fix this error?

Comment: This is also a good answer:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18495/visual-studio-not-ignoring-files-specified-in-the.html

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this by

- Add *.jfm as a line to the local .gitignore
- Close the solution (but stay connected in Team Explorer)
- Delete the .jfm file in file explorer
- Commit the .jfm deletion and the .gitignore edit
- Reopen the solution and rebuild
- Should see that there are no .jfm changes

Answer (score 2):

I happened upon a post on the visual studio forum, and used some of the information provided there to point me in the right direction.  see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/18495/visual-studio-not-ignoring-files-specified-in-the.html)

however, an additional error occurred when trying to `Sync` the changes,

> An error occurred. Detailed message: 1 conflict prevents checkout

additional steps were needed, perhaps because sql services were running on the local machine.

this process worked for me:

- in the local visual studio app, add `*.jfm` to the `# User-specific files` section of the local .gitignore file
- exit visual studio locally
- remove the `.jfm` file from the remote repo by logging into the visualstudio.com account and deleting the file there.
- open `Services` on the local machine
- stop any sql services that may be running
- rename the local `.jfm` file and its file extension (e.g. rename the file to  `sqlfile-jfm.original`)
- re-start the sql services
- re-start visual studio locally
- update the local repo using `Unsynced Commits` -> `Pull`

hope this helps others with a similar problem.