# .jfm file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, ssis

I have a Data Tools project with github on Visual Studio. When I commit my changes, .jfm files show up and they often conflict when I am pulling changes from others.

When I accept .jfm files from others, I lose my changes.

What are those files? How should they be managed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Database Project directory contains a file with extension jfm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704514/visual-studio-2015-database-project-directory-contains-a-file-with-extension-jfm)