# Git failed with a fatal error. error: open permission denied fatal: unable to process path

Tags: git

I have problem when I want to commit changes to my tabular model.
I got the following error: 
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open("Application/Source/'texthere'/'texthere'.jfm"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path Application/Source/'texthere'/'texthere.jfm

I've opened .gitignore file and there is *.jfm extension included.

I was trying to find something online but without success.

Comment: `ls -l Application/Source/'texthere'/'texthere'.jfm` ?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look here for details on this behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39456723/9776462

To make sure jfm-files are not handeled by git anymore, do the following:

- Add "*.jfm" to .gitignore
- make sure, git does not already track the jfm-file. If it already tracks, remove it with `git rm <jfm-file>` (you probably have to close Visual Studio for git rm to work)
- remove the file from any remote branches/repos and resync

Answer (score 3):

*.jfm file is used when the project is opened. So, unload the project to commit the file. But, it would be better to remove the *.jfm files from repository as n00ne explained.

Comment: same problem was with database project in VS2019 (cannot open *.dbmdl file, permission denied) - thank you for solution!

Answer (score 0):

Create a bare clone of the repository:

```sh
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
```

Mirror-push to the new repository:

```sh
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add *.jfm line into the local .gitignore.
- Close the solution
- Delete the .jfm file from the database project.
- Reopen Solution and commit.